# XML Parse in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am trying to parse XML document inside of T-SQL. XML Document look like when there is some clients:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
<ArrayOfServerSettings>
   <ServerSettings>
     <Address>10.0.1.1</Address>
     <Nodes>
        <NodeSettings>
            <PortNumber>5000</PortNumber>
            <ClientIds>
                <int>1</int>
                <int>2</int>
                <int>3</int>
            </ClientIds>
        </NodeSettings>
      </Nodes>
   </ServerSettings>
</ArrayOfServerSettings>
```

if there is no any clients, it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
<ArrayOfServerSettings>
   <ServerSettings>
     <Address>10.0.1.1</Address>
     <Nodes>
        <NodeSettings>
            <PortNumber>5000</PortNumber>
            <ClientIds />
        </NodeSettings>
      </Nodes>
   </ServerSettings>
</ArrayOfServerSettings>
```

In the first case, the table should look like

```
Address     PortNumber     ClientId
10.0.1.1      5000           1
10.0.1.1      5000           2
10.0.1.1      5000           3
```

When there is no client I should parse them like

```
Address     PortNumber     ClientId
10.0.1.1      5000           0
```

Here is my t-sql statements

```
declare @xml XML
set @xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfCalculationServerSettings>
   <CalculationServerSettings>
      <Address>10.0.1.1</Address>
      <Nodes>
         <NodeSettings>
            <PortNumber>10009</PortNumber>
            <ClientIds>
               <int>1</int>
               <int>2</int>
               <int>3</int>
            </ClientIds>
         </NodeSettings>
      </Nodes>
  </CalculationServerSettings>
```

'

```
DECLARE @DocID INT 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocID OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT *   
FROM
    OPENXML(@DocID, '/ArrayOfServerSettings/ServerSettings/Nodes/NodeSettings/ClientIds/int', 1)
    WITH (
        Address NVARCHAR(256) '../../../../Address[1]',
        PortNumber    INT           '../../PortNumber[1]',
        ClientID      INT           '.'
    ) AS D0

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocID
```

**But my approach is not working for the second option**

Comment: Why are you not using XQuery? SQL Server has supported it since 2005 (iirc). Are you using a very *old* version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am not familiar with XQuery, if you know, please could you help me

Comment: Can we *assume* your XML is valid? The XML in your query is not (it does not close the `ArrayOfCalculationServerSettings` node).

Comment: Yeap, typo mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can *assume* that you have valid XML (yours is not), and that you only have 1 PortNumber node, you could do this:

```sql
declare @xml XML
set @xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfCalculationServerSettings>
   <CalculationServerSettings>
      <Address>10.0.1.1</Address>
      <Nodes>
         <NodeSettings>
            <PortNumber>10009</PortNumber>
            <ClientIds>
               <int>1</int>
               <int>2</int>
               <int>3</int>
            </ClientIds>
         </NodeSettings>
      </Nodes>
  </CalculationServerSettings>
</ArrayOfCalculationServerSettings>'; --This is missing in your XML

SELECT ACSS.CSS.value('(Address/text())[1]','nvarchar(15)') AS Address,
       ACSS.CSS.value('(Nodes/NodeSettings/PortNumber/text())[1]','int') AS PortNumber, --I assume always the same port number
       ISNULL(CS.I.value('text()[1]','int'),0) AS int
FROM @xml.nodes('ArrayOfCalculationServerSettings/CalculationServerSettings') ACSS(CSS)
     OUTER APPLY ACSS.CSS.nodes('Nodes/NodeSettings/ClientIds/int')CS(I);
```

If you have multiple port numbers, with more `int` values, then you'll need to do some further nesting of the `nodes` methods.